# How do I add my .shp file as a Vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, vector, vector-layer

I'm working in QGIS 3.12 and my university as given us zip files of "data" for each practical we do. I've unzipped it and followed steps of adding a vector layer and navigating to the right file to add the layer. But each time I can see it in the list of layers in the bottom right of the screen but not as an actual map in the project. I've attached a picture of what I see once I've added it. I've tried closing and starting the project again but other than that I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Try right clicking on the layer and select "zoom to layer". Can you then see the points?

Comment: Does the point file have any features?

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I did those things suggested and then found that it was an issue with the zip file. The first time I unzipped it I guess something went wrong, the content was only 1kb but then I did it again and the content increased so was unzipped properly. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

Here are things I do when I don't see data from a layer:

1. Right click the layer and `Zoom to layer` to see if it is just **located** elsewhere, or at a much different **scale** (your scale in the bottom right is a rather high number)
2. Double click on the layer and choose the information icon (i first from the top). Check that **CRS** is specified (and correct), and that **feature count** is >0.

CRS missing or incorrect is not unusual, especially for shapefiles. You can fix it by right clicking the layer and selecting `Layer CRS`.

Zero features should not happen for shape files unless they are corrupt (or perhaps missing some of the component files?), but can happen when data is being imported from another format, or from a database or server that is not responding.

3. (Advanced, and unlikely in your case, but adding for completeness) If the layer came from a gpkg, or was copied from another project, or a layer description file, check the **symbology**, to make sure colors aren't invisible (e.g. white on white), that there is not a scale restriction on rendering, that categorized or rule based renderer criteria are not corrupt, and that data-defined overrides aren't making things invisible or relying on expressions that have errors (e.g. missing fields).

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I did those things suggested and then found that it was an issue with the zip file. The first time I unzipped it I guess something went wrong, the content was only 1kb but then I did it again and the content increased so was unzipped properly. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it was an issue with the zip file. The first time I unzipped it I guess something went wrong, the content was only 1kb but then I did it again and the content increased a lot so was unzipped properly. Thankyou for your answers!